# Express (Nodejs package) doesn't work on Ubuntu x64 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, failed-installation

Decided to try out Express. Installed it via

```
sudo npm install express -g
sudo npm install express-generator -g
```

(Had to use sudo cause the installer was unable to get access to **/usr/bin/express**)

When trying to create an Express project ... nothing happens

```
dog@ubuntu:~/Documents/sources/ShopsForEveryone/Code$ express Shops4Everyone
dog@ubuntu:~/Documents/sources/ShopsForEveryone/Code$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 dog dog 4096 Nov  4 21:52 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 dog dog 4096 Nov  4 19:04 ..
```

Tried to install Express globally and locally (via **npm init** in current directory), nothing helps.

Comment: what if "express ./Shops4Everyone" or "express ~/Documents/sources/ShopsForEveryone/Code/Shops4Everyone" ?

Comment: You installed express as super user, so you should run express command with sudo

Comment: Tried to launch through sudo, same result. Even issuing **express -h** does nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo npm install -g express-generator

 sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

 npm install express --save

 express myapp
```

The nodejs-legacy install saved my biscuits you might want to try that im using a lubuntu 15.04.